# Construction material and stack effect

Tags: aerodynamics

In a stack, tower or chimney aimed at exploiting the updraught of air due to the stack effect, would the material that the stack is constructed from impact the flow velocity up the stack? Would the level of insulation due the selected construction material (e.g. concrete vs steel) potentially lead to more or less of a differential between the inner and outer temperatures, thus influencing the stack effect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will, just as you suspect.

To maintain a draft in a chimney, the flue gases in it must be buoyant relative to the gas surrounding the stack. This means they have to be warmer than ambient. A flue pipe made of thin steel will conduct that warmth away from the flue gas and into the ambient, losing buoyancy in the process, and diminishing the chimney effect. If the chimney is made of masonry or concrete, this effect will be minimized.

A steel flue can be operated as a chimney if it is run hot enough to maintain a high flow velocity in the pipe; in this way the flue gases will be exhausted out the top of the stack before there's sufficient time for heat losses to accrue as the gases rise up and out.